# GridView using Table Layout Android

Tags: android, gridview, android-tablelayout

I am basically trying to create a gridview kind of a thing using TableLayout. I am getting the horizontal thing(2 columns) working fine. But each item is getting cut and looks like is taking up only 50dp height and not 120dp height as mentioned in the table_row.xml

```
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
                final TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(MyActivity.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity.this);
                final LinearLayout tableRowLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row, null);

                tableRow.addView(tableRowLayout);

             tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
            }
```

My table_layout.xml

```
    <TableLayout
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/myTableLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="0">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/myTableRow"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"></TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
```

My table_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_height="120dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/imageone"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sofa"
            android:id="@+id/twoImage"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Nested weights were the cause to this problem. We generally ignore the warning about nested weights causing performance issues, even UI issues are caused.

I modified my table_row.xml like this and it worked

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/OneImage"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/TwoImage"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```